# Необходимо сделать так, чтобы через определенное время менялся текст в JTextField

Tags: java

Хочу по истечении промежутка времени менять в textField значения, скрыв перед этим кнопку и показав данное окно. Задумка не удается, при нажатии на кнопку программа застывает и только после окончания цикла выдает конечный результат, выполнив нужные действия. Помогите!

```
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                int a;
                if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
                    a = 1;
                } else a = 0;
                btn.setVisible(false);
                textField.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 15));
                textField.setVisible(true);
                try {
                    for (; time > 0; time -= 1) {
                        Thread.sleep(time * 100);
                        if (time % 2 == a) {
                            textField.setText("YOU << BOT");
                        } else {
                            textField.setText("YOU >> BOT");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("error");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: `ScheduledExecutorService`

Comment: Все как и написано - Timer.sleep останавливает выполнение всей програмы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте для этого javax.swing.Timer
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

использовать Thread.sleep - это плохая идея

Answer (score 0):

Перерисовку компонентов надо делать в отдельном потоке, иначе все перерисуется только после окончания цикла. Можно так

```
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                int a;
                if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
                    a = 1;
                } else a = 0;
                btn.setVisible(false);
                textField.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 15));
                textField.setVisible(true);
                try {
                    for (; time > 0; time -= 1) {
                        Thread.sleep(time * 100);
                        if (time % 2 == a) {
                             SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void run() {
                                      textField.setText("YOU << BOT");
                                  }
                             });
                        } else {
                             SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void run() {
                                      textField.setText("YOU >> BOT");
                                  }
                             });

                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("error");
                }
            }
        });
```

Или используйте SwingWorker. Подробнее можно посмотреть [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html)